# How to calibrate screen color in Ubuntu BY EYE (as in, without additional hardware)

Tags: display, colors

My Dell Inspiron 14 7000 laptop has a screen that has a slightly yellow color. In Windows, there is a tool that allows me to manually adjust the color of the display to have less red and green to correct for this. However, in Ubuntu most of the color calibration tools involve using a hardware tool to precisely calibrate the display.

I do not have this hardware, but the warm tone annoys me. How can I correct for this in Ubuntu?

Answer (score -1):

You can try [RedShift](http://jonls.dk/redshift/)

It's not a color calibration tool but,

> Redshift adjusts the color temperature of your screen according to your surroundings.

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for something that can make the "whites" actually look white by reducing the amount of red and green